# When I use URLSession.dataTask to complete some job, my var always resets

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I want to get some data or complete some job when I request web service. But when I use `URLSession.dataTask` method to do this, my var always resets. Why?

It is the case when I set the breakpoint in the `func checkToken()`, the var `iftokened` is `true` because the responseStatus is "200". But when it is back to `func viewDidLoad()`, the var `iftokened` is reset. When I print it, it is `false`. Why? How to fix it?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkToken()
        print(iftokened)
    }

    var iftokened = false

    func checkToken() {
        fetchToken { [weak self] (responseStatus) in
            if responseStatus == "200" {
                self?.iftokened = true
            } else {
                self?.iftokened = false
            }
        }
    }

    let session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: config)
    }()

    func fetchToken(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        let urlString = "http://www.google.com"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            completion("200")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a peek here. https://www.raywenderlich.com/158106/urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying is asynchronous as the session runs in a separate thread other than the main thread so while calling the url control passes to next line which is the print statement that prints false as the variable isn't yet changed by the response call completion

```
func checkToken() {
    fetchToken { [weak self] (responseStatus) in
        if responseStatus == "200" {
            self?.iftokened = true
        } else {
            self?.iftokened = false
        }

         print(iftokened)

         /// start using iftokened here 
    }
}
```

Comment: @cRuiTe There's nothing to fix. The only issue with your code is that your print statement in `viewDidLoad` is being called long before the token is actually retrieved. Put the print statement inside the proper location in the `checkToken` method instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to get current token status

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkToken(completion: { [weak self] response in
        self?.iftokened = response
        print(self?.iftokened ?? false)
    })
}

var iftokened = false

func checkToken(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
    fetchToken { (responseStatus) in
       if responseStatus == "200" {
           completion(true)
       } else {
           completion(false)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a sync request by using semophore

```
func fetchToken(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
       let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        let urlString = "http://www.google.com"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            let task = self.session.dataTask(with: request) {
                (data, response, error) in

                completion("200")
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            task.resume()
        semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    }
```

But you code have other problems as well:

- You should get response status from server when the request has finished, instead of using completion ("200") at the callback

  ```
  if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {               
   completion(response.statusCode)
  }
  ```

Comment: This is a terrible idea. The whole point of using a completion handler is to properly deal with the asynchronous nature of the method. Blocking the return using a semaphore and using a completion handler makes no sense at all.